# U-Boot application causes reset

Tags: fpga, u-boot, riscv

This question might be too broad and may not be easily understandable until you see actual code or what is happening, but I thought I should give at least a try. I am porting U-boot for RISCV cpu on MAX10 FPGA in its DDR3 Memory. I have made all the necessary configurations for my specific board and processor as mentioned in the README of U-boot and it is successfully built as well.

But, currently I am unable to get into U-boot application for some reason. Whenever I prompt it to enter into address that I have specified in CONFIG_SYS_LOAD_ADDR which is 0x80000000, it resets and starts from address 0x00000000. I don't have any idea that why is this happening. Can someone expert with this stuff help me?

Answer (score 2):

> Whenever I prompt it to enter into address that I have specified in CONFIG_SYS_LOAD_ADDR which is 0x80000000, it resets and starts from address 0x00000000.

**CONFIG_SYS_LOAD_ADDR** is merely a default load address for various U-Boot commands (e.g. `tftpboot`).
The symbol that does need to be defined is **CONFIG_STANDALONE_LOAD_ADDR**, which is used as the linker address for standalone applications.

The U-Boot standalone applications are built as non-relocatable code.
Since your application was built with an unknown default link address, it is unlikely to properly execute at 0x80000000.

If you haven't already, you should also perform a memory test using U-Boot's `memtest`.